# How to enable gRPC logging for akka.grpc?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, grpc

Unsure if I have done the right thing. I found this link : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/client/configuration.html#debug-logging and followed the steps exactly but do not see any "FINE" logging being printed on the console. I don't see any stream-like data being printed on my console. In my application I have a couple of libraries which invoke GRPC calls to external services and I'd like to enable debugging so I can see the output being received.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Are you sure that you have set the path correctly? -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/grpc-debug-logging.properties

Comment: Yep! I set it to the absolute path!